# TypeError: "quotechar" must be an 1-character string

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I am trying to read data from a csv file. I set quotechar to csv.QUOTE_NONE.

The four lines of Python I wrote for this purpose are just as follows -

```
import csv
with open('mtz.gps.comfort_gps_logs_20110214_20110215.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    taxiDataReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in taxiDataReader:
        print row
```

However, when I run these, I get this error message -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log.py", line 3, in <module>
    taxiDataReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
TypeError: "quotechar" must be an 1-character string
```

I would not only like to understand why this particular error shows up but also understand in more detail what the role of quotechar really is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`QUOTE_NONE` is meant as a value for the parameter `quoting`, not for `quotechar`.

The correct way would be to use

```
taxiDataReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

[The docs state](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) that `quotechar` must always be a one-character string, its role is simply to choose which character should be used for quoting.

Quoting becomes necessary in a variety of situations, for example

- if a CSV field contains the separator character (e. g. a comma)
- if a CSV field contains a linefeed characters.

In both these cases the CSV reader needs to know that these characters are meant as literal characters, not as control characters. So, if you wanted to put the values `[1, "hello", "1,2,3", "hi\nthere"]` into a CSV file, it would be quite bad if the result was

```
1,hello,1,2,3,hi
there
```

wouldn't it? Therefore, these fields are quoted:

```
1,hello,"1,2,3","hi\nthere"
```

`quoting` controls what will be quoted when (defaulting to `QUOTE_MINIMAL`, i.e., only when quotes are absolutely necessary). If you turn off quoting entirely (`QUOTE_NONE`), the value of `quotechar` is of course meaningless.

Comment: I still don't clearly understand what the roles of quotechar and quoting are. Why should something be quoted? It will be awesome if you could please explain this using some csv data as an example so that I can understand the need. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: But then, does QUOTE_NONE have any significance while reading the CSV file? The fields which were to be quoted have already been quoted. Also, could you please elaborate on quotechar too? Thanks for your patience and effort :)

Comment: I think I understood it myself. Please correct me if I am wrong. quotechar is the character which will be used for quoting. quoting controls what will be quoted.