# Python3 avoid quoting and extra lines at the end of the csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to create a CSV file based on a list content created and concatenated previously. The deal is that all my lines records are coming with double quotes the beginning and at the end of every line. In addition at the end of the file, I am getting an extra white line.

**Code:**

```
with open('/tmp/'+filename,"w", newline='') as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output)
            for item in update_records:
                row = '{},{},{}'.format(item['field1'],item['field2'],item['field3'])
                #print(row)
                writer.writerow([row])               

        output.close()
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**I have tried:**

```
writer = csv.writer(output, quotechar='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

But I am getting errors like:

> quotechar must be set if quoting enabled

thanks so much for the support.

Comment: `quotechar` is passed the character you want to use as a quote. Passing in an empty string there is making it confused. Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833209/typeerror-quotechar-must-be-an-1-character-string)

Comment: If you want to use **'** as `quotechar` than you have to pass `quotechar="'"`

Comment: Please consider the answer @Gelineau, as you probably do not want to store this in quotes in the first place writing a list of strings is what you want to separate them, otherwise this will not really be a CSV.

Comment: The `output.close()` is unnecessary when using the with statement. What should your desired output look like ? Why does the final blank line bother you, I have been there before too, a properly formatted CSV would have a line terminator and it must be terminated also for the last entry which makes it look like it. You can bend that rule, but then you would have to deal with exceptions here in writing and whoever is reading it too.

Answer (score 2):

Here an answer using DictWriter instead, but an amount of guesswork based on the structure of data. There are even easier ways to write it, e.g. you have them as a list of dictionaries.

```
import csv

update_records = [
    {
        "field1": "field1",
        "field2": "en",
        "field3": "field3"
    },
    {
        "field1": "field1",
        "field2": "de",
        "field3": "field3"
    }
]

filename = "test.csv"

with open('/tmp/'+filename,"w", newline='') as output:
    # Define header, needed even if not written when using DictWriter
    header = ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=header)
    # Optional write the header
    # writer.writeheader()
    for item in update_records:
        row = {}
        # Only provide the fields 1 to 1 that are present in the header.
        # There are plenty of cooler ways to do this, but hope this is clearer.
        for head in header:
            row[head] = item[head]
        # print(row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Output is as such (/tmp/test.csv) (there is a blank line at the end, however no idea how to show this as part of the code so added EOF):

```
field1,en,field3
field1,de,field3

EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

writerow should take a list of fields as argument:

```
with open('/tmp/'+filename,"w", newline='') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for item in update_records:
        row = [item['field1'],item['field2'],item['field3']]
        #print(row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: By using with you can omit the output.close() as it will be done automatically. And it would be great if you could update your indentation. From a solution perspective I think you are correct, the quote char is not the real problem (at least not yet)

Comment: Sorry I just realized you copied his code and modified it as such.

Comment: You were right, I should not have copied the code as is

Comment: this is giving : "[field1, 'en', field3]"

Comment: Given the way you address items, I assume dictwriter may be a better fit for you, but a simple example row would help to guide you to success

Comment: Modify `writer.writerow([row])` to `writer.writerow(row)`, it is already a list, no need to put it in one