# "TypeError: quotechar must be set if quoting enabled" In csv module

Tags: python, csv

When creating a `csv.DictReader` with parameters from the configuration (or using the default values if they're not set), I get the following error message:

```
File "/Users/deangurvitz/temp.py", line 89, in <module>
  with csv.DictReader(f, quotechar=None) as reader:
File ".../3.7/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 87, in __init__
  self.reader = reader(f, dialect, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: quotechar must be set if quoting enabled
```

The relevant code snippet is:

```
delimiter = config.csv_separator if config.csv_separator else ','
escape_char = config.csv_escape if config.csv_escape else None
quote_char = config.csv_quote if config.csv_quote else None
return csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=delimiter, escapechar=escape_char, quotechar=quote_char)
```

I have already stumbled upon several questions dealing with a `TypeError: “quotechar” must be an 1-character string` (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833209/typeerror-quotechar-must-be-an-1-character-string)), but this is not the case here since the `quotechar` parameter isn't given an invalid value. What might be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case was that I passed a `None` value to the `quotechar` parameter, which is only allowed if quoting is explicitly disabled using the additional parameter `quoting=QUOTE_NONE` (more information about these formatting parameters is given [in the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params)). The default value for the `quotechar` parameter isn't `None`, but rather `'"'`, and using that as the default value in my code as well solved the problem.

Comment: The manual doesn't specify the information I shared here explicitly (at least not the regular doc pages). No where in the provided link it addresses the case of providing None to the parameter `quotechar`. It is possible that after reading a different, more detailed page about the `quoting` parameter, this would become more obvious, but one might not even know that he needs to read that section since the `quoting` parameter isn't even specified in the code.

Comment: True the manual doesn't cover every possible erroneous combination possible, but it doesn't surprise me that the `quoting=` formatting parameter is what controls whether things are quoted and that what the `quotechar` is defined to be only matters if quoting is enabled.